# I want normalize data by dividing every row by the price on the first row

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I have a dataframe in pandas. I want to normalize my Close column by dividing every row by the price on the first row. This is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

bova=yf.download('BOVA11.SA',
                 start='2014-01-01',
                 end='2021-12-31',
                 progress=False,
                 )
bova
```

output:

```
              Open          High     Low          Close     Adj Close   Volume
Date                    
2014-01-02  50.220001   50.270000   49.060001   49.080002   49.080002   1001210
2014-01-03  49.099998   49.470001   49.049999   49.259998   49.259998   1227270
2014-01-06  49.259998   49.990002   49.200001   49.840000   49.840000   702060
2014-01-07  49.549999   50.290001   49.230000   49.230000   49.230000   1304100
2014-01-08  49.540001   49.590000   49.209999   49.279999   49.279999   951950
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-12-23  101.599998  101.599998  100.709999  100.849998  100.849998  5047637
2021-12-27  101.400002  101.800003  100.949997  101.599998  101.599998  5274352
2021-12-28  101.830002  101.830002  100.589996  101.059998  101.059998  7167734
2021-12-29  101.239998  101.349998  99.940002   100.250000  100.250000  7343838
2021-12-30  100.809998  101.449997  100.290001  100.800003  100.800003  3404622
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
bova['Norm Close'] = bova['Close'] / bova['Close'][0]
print(bova[['Close', 'Norm Close']])

# Output
                 Close  Norm Close
Date                              
2014-01-02   49.080002    1.000000
2014-01-03   49.259998    1.003667
2014-01-06   49.840000    1.015485
2014-01-07   49.230000    1.003056
2014-01-08   49.279999    1.004075
...                ...         ...
2021-12-23  100.849998    2.054808
2021-12-27  101.599998    2.070090
2021-12-28  101.059998    2.059087
2021-12-29  100.250000    2.042583
2021-12-30  100.800003    2.053790

[1986 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

So something like this?

```
for c in df.columns:
    if c != 'Date':
        df[c] = df[c]/df[c][0]
```

This will iterate every column of the dataframe except for `Date`, and will divide it by the value of the corresponding column of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
bova.div(bova.iloc[0])
```

`iloc[0]` will give you the first row of the dataframe. you divide each row, including the first row, by the first row values. so your first row values will have value 1. if you want to start from 100

```
bova.div(bova.iloc[0]).mul(100)
```